# Stop animation specific step

Tags: css, animation

I have a one animiation code. The essence of the code is that a background file goes ahead in advance, four times. However, I want in step 4 not to stop at the image end, i want at step 8 of end the four repeat.

```
.win_1 {
display: block;
width: 485px;
height: 429px;
background: url(https://image.ibb.co/fTh91T/spirate.jpg) left center;
animation: cc1 0.5s steps(12) forwards;
position: fixed;
animation-iteration-count: 4;
}

@keyframes cc1 {
100% { background-position: -5808px; }
```

So, its possible, of stop the animiation of specific step (example 8. step)?